# cts:uris and cts:search returning different results

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8

I have a strange issue, I am doing cts:uri and cts:search.. And my cts:uris gives me 7 results where as cts:search only gives 3 results..

Not sure what I am doing wrong, hoping someone can point me what I am doing wrong. I tried all possibilities that I know of :).. following the code that I am running

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
declare namespace html = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml";
import module namespace search = "http://marklogic.com/appservices/search" at "/MarkLogic/appservices/search/search.xqy";

    let $q := '(Dermatolog*) AND ((context:KN)) AND ((gene:"STAT3") AND (indication:"Carcinoma")) AND ((uploadDate:"today")) AND (sort:date_desc)' 


    let $options := 
        <options xmlns="http://marklogic.com/appservices/search">
        <additional-query>
            <cts:collection-query xmlns:cts="http://marklogic.com/cts">
                <cts:uri>http://abc/xyz/type/envelope</cts:uri>
            </cts:collection-query>
        </additional-query>
        <operator name="sort">
            <state name="date_desc">
                <sort-order type="xs:dateTime" direction="descending">
                    <field name="upload_date"/>
                </sort-order>
            </state>
            <state name="date_asc">
                <sort-order type="xs:dateTime" direction="ascending">
                    <field name="upload_date"/>
                </sort-order>
            </state>
        </operator>
        <constraint name="context">
            <range type="xs:string" facet="true">
                <element name="context" ns="http://abc/xyz/metadata"/>
                <facet-option>frequency-order</facet-option>
                <facet-option>descending</facet-option>
            </range>
        </constraint>
        <constraint name="type">
            <range type="xs:string" facet="true">
                <element name="type" ns="http://abc/xyz/metadata"/>
                <facet-option>frequency-order</facet-option>
                <facet-option>descending</facet-option>
            </range>
        </constraint>
        <constraint name="file-type">
            <range type="xs:string" facet="true">
                <element name="file-type" ns="http://abc/xyz/metadata"/>
                <facet-option>frequency-order</facet-option>
                <facet-option>descending</facet-option>
            </range>
        </constraint>
        <constraint name="drug">
            <range type="xs:string" facet="true">
                <path-index>//Hit[@type='DRUG']/Name</path-index>
                <facet-option>frequency-order</facet-option>
                <facet-option>descending</facet-option>
                <facet-option>limit=10</facet-option>
            </range>
        </constraint>
        <constraint name="compound">
            <range type="xs:string" facet="true">
                <path-index>//Hit[@type='COMPOUNDS']/Name</path-index>
                <facet-option>frequency-order</facet-option>
                <facet-option>descending</facet-option>
                <facet-option>limit=10</facet-option>
            </range>
        </constraint>
        <constraint name="species">
            <range type="xs:string" facet="true">
                <path-index>//Hit[@type='SPECIES']/Name</path-index>
                <facet-option>frequency-order</facet-option>
                <facet-option>descending</facet-option>
                <facet-option>limit=10</facet-option>
            </range>
        </constraint>
        <constraint name="company">
            <range type="xs:string" facet="true">
                <path-index>//Hit[@type='COMPANY']/Name</path-index>
                <facet-option>frequency-order</facet-option>
                <facet-option>descending</facet-option>
                <facet-option>limit=10</facet-option>
            </range>
        </constraint>
        <constraint name="indication">
            <range type="xs:string" facet="true">
                <path-index>//Hit[@type='INDICATION']/Name</path-index>
                <facet-option>frequency-order</facet-option>
                <facet-option>descending</facet-option>
                <facet-option>limit=10</facet-option>
            </range>
        </constraint>
        <constraint name="gene">
            <range type="xs:string" facet="true">
                <path-index>//Hit[@type='GENE']/@id</path-index>
                <facet-option>frequency-order</facet-option>
                <facet-option>descending</facet-option>
                <facet-option>limit=10</facet-option>
            </range>
        </constraint>
        <constraint name="uploadDate">
            <range type="xs:dateTime" facet="true">
                <computed-bucket lt="P1D" ge="P0D" anchor="start-of-day" name="today">Today</computed-bucket>
                <computed-bucket lt="P0D" ge="-P1D" anchor="start-of-day" name="yesterday">Yesterday</computed-bucket>
                <computed-bucket lt="-P1D" ge="-P15D" anchor="start-of-day" name="2-weeks">Last 2 Weeks</computed-bucket>
                <computed-bucket lt="-P15D" ge="-P30D" anchor="start-of-day" name="month">A Month ago</computed-bucket>
                <computed-bucket lt="-P30D" ge="-P365D" anchor="start-of-day" name="year">A Year ago</computed-bucket>
                <computed-bucket name="older"  lt="-P365D" anchor="start-of-day">Older</computed-bucket>
                <facet-option>descending</facet-option>
                <field name="upload_date"/>
            </range>
        </constraint>
        <constraint name="author">
            <range type="xs:string" facet="true">
                <facet-option>frequency-order</facet-option>
                <facet-option>descending</facet-option>
                <facet-option>limit=10</facet-option>
                <field name="author"/>
            </range>
        </constraint>
        <term>
            <term-option>case-insensitive</term-option>
            <term-option>punctuation-insensitive</term-option>
            <term-option>whitespace-insensitive</term-option>
            <term-option>wildcarded</term-option>
        </term>
        <return-facets>true</return-facets>
        <return-results>true</return-results>
        <transform-results apply="empty-snippet"/>
    </options>


    return
     (
       cts:uris("", ('document'), cts:query(search:parse($q, $options))),
       cts:search(fn:doc(), cts:query(search:parse($q, $options)))
     )
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is the effect of filtered vs. unfiltered queries. `cts:uris` can only be run unfiltered, which means that it only uses indexes and may return false positives, depending on your index settings. `cts:search` filters queries by default, and you have to specify `unfiltered` in the options parameter.

Also note that most options specified in your `<search:options>` element are *NOT* applied automatically when you use `cts:search` instead of `search:resolve`, including `<additional-query>`.

Comment: Is this same for faceting??

Comment: Yes, that's correct. All lexicon-based functions will only run unfiltered.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.. filtered vs unfiltered always gets me